# How to talk to customer service TAP's to receive a refund

Tags: refunds, covid-19, tap-portugal

I booked a ticket in December (before the Coronavirus outbreak made it outside of China) to fly from Lisbon to Tel Aviv in May, on the 24th of March TAP cancelled the flight.

From what I understand I should be able to receive a full money refund according to the EU261 regulation. And also according to the flight contract with TAP (I read parts of it, preparing to talk with their customer service).

But I called their customer support (minimum of 30 minutes waiting time, answered me 5 out of 7 calls) and they just offer me a voucher, when I ask for the refund they refuse, and when I mention the laws they disconnect the call.

I decided to try to record them and told them I will, which resulted in claims that it is illegal, and then they disconnected me.

So my questions are:
1) (Important) How can I actually talk them into giving me my money back?
2) (Less important) Is it illegal to record a talk with customer service? Do I have to tell them I am doing it?

Thanks!

PS. right now I filed with my CC company to see if they can give me the money back, but in case that doesn't work, I would like to be able to talk better to customer support.

Comment: For the question about legality of recording, please post a question on the Law SE.  Otherwise, dont expect much out of TAP, they were on the cusp of bankruptcy before this hit, they wont have the money to cover tens of thousands of refunds - you did the right thing in approaching your credit card company.

Comment: See my answer to https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/155331/tap-airlines-refusing-refund-of-top-executive-tickets

Comment: @moo - no this is not the same, as TAP cancelled my flight. I didn't want to cancel.

Everyone else, thanks for the information, this doesn't really make sense, since those same governments won't let me cheat people out of money if I was getting poor. But I know this is reality.

Comment: @NurBar if the company has no money, it cant pay out, its as simple as that.  Its got nothing to do with the government letting this happen, these airlines cash flows are being devastated.

Comment: @moo - yea I know, I know. I'm not going to get into a comparison of how a company get handled when they don't have money vs. a person without money... So we'll leave it at that.