# TAP Airlines refusing refund of Top Executive tickets

Tags: refunds, covid-19, tap-portugal

We have fully refundable "Top Executive" tickets but they are refusing to give refunds. Only credit vouchers. Unacceptable. Has anyone been successful in getting refund rather than a voucher which has very limited date for when it can be used.  What recourse is there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a refund from TAP Air Portugal related to COVID-19](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/154658/getting-a-refund-from-tap-air-portugal-related-to-covid-19)

Answer (score 5):

Currently many airlines are refusing refunds and offering travel vouchers or re-booking instead, even in cases where they are legally required to give a cash refund.

It will be very difficult to enforce your legal rights here since some governments might actually give legal cover to the airlines (France for example) and are unlikely to enforce existing laws. There has already been filed a class action lawsuit in Canada against Air Canada.

Your best shot is probably to try a charge back with your credit card company.

Comment: +1 to chargeback. Airlines are going bankrupt. Don't let them steal your money along the way.

Comment: Easier said than done, though. Amex France is currently refusing any chargebacks

Comment: wow that's heavy, @Hilmar

Comment: Heavy but apparently true: https://liveandletsfly.com/2020/03/26/air-france-american-express-conspiracy/ Canadian government has actually legalized the "voucher instead of cash" law breaking: onemileatatime.com/canada-refund-flight-cancelled/