# We had our flights cancelled by Covid 19 Virus closures

Tags: air-travel, tap-portugal

We were scheduled to travel Toronto to Lisbon on April 3-April 11,2020. The flights have been subsequently cancelled. We purchased the refundable type tickets which basically mean we will be charged 350.00 for each ticket. A far cry from the 2500 I spent. Problem is that they are not allowing me to refund any portion instead offer a voucher for a year. Not only is my 8 year old crushed by the fact that his tournament in Algarve is cancelled,but I am stuck with the fact that we are not and will not need a voucher. Why on a refundable ticket is there no way to get funds returned. They said they didn't cancel the flights, the Portuguese government did! Are they not owned by the government. So Sad!!!

Comment: You are being forced to take a voucher because the airline has no money - they were on the cusp of bankruptcy for years and this current crisis hasnt done them any favours at all.  Contact your credit card and request a charge back, or investigate what other options your credit card provider has to recover your money.

Comment: This does NOT appear to be a duplicate, since OP's flight was cancelled by the airline, not by the passenger. That creates a very different legal situation. The outcome may still be the same, though. Better match might be https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/155331/tap-airlines-refusing-refund-of-top-executive-tickets