# Refunds if first leg of Airticket is cancelled - Lufthansa premium economy

Tags: cancellations, refunds, lufthansa

I had booked a one way Premium Economy ticket with Lufthansa on the following itinerary for me and my daughter

31st March - Bangalore - Frankfurt - Vancouver - Saskatoon

I had booked a return ticket with Lufthansa on the following itinerary for my husband

31st March - Bangalore - Frankfurt - Vancouver - Saskatoon

22nd May - Saskatoon - Calgary - Frankfurt - Bangalore

On the 18th of March, Lufthansa cancelled the first leg (Bangalore - Frankfurt) of both journeys because of the COVID 19 situation. I then went online and cancelled both tickets. I am not sure why but Lufthansa does not clearly point out the cancellation policy of the ticket once you buy it. When I look at the terms of the Premium Economy tickets sold for the same itinerary in the future they state "Cancellation - refund possible plus fare difference". I am really worried that Lufthansa will not refund my tickets. The call center is simply not reachable. Can anyone tell me how I can figure out if my premium economy tickets were refundable and what my options are if I do not hear from them in 4 weeks?

Comment: My husband's tickets were also premium economy

Comment: There might be information of value to you in https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/155331/tap-airlines-refusing-refund-of-top-executive-tickets

Comment: You will probably find an answer here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/156398/when-does-a-flight-count-as-cancelled-by-the-airline-partial-cancellation

Comment: Have you resolved the topic? "Premium Economy" is a bucket and not an exact fare base code (like for example: D03BXXE0), so more information is needed.