# When does a flight count as "cancelled" by the airline? (partial cancellation)

Tags: cancellations, refunds, covid-19

We had booked a Boston<->Mumbai itinerary with Expedia on Air France. Original flights were operated by Air France, KLM, Vistara & Delta. Obviously we can't go since the countries are in lock down and our Visas have been suspended.

Most legs have already been cancelled but Expedia still shows the full itinerary. Air France shows only bits and pieces: the whole itinerary it now consists of a one flight from Paris to Amsterdam and another one from Paris to New York. Neither flight touches our original departure or destination airport. However Air France still shows it as active. We have active cancellation notifications from KLM and Vistara for two of the legs. Air France and Delta have cancelled or re-booked silently.

Trying to call OTA or Air France at the moment is impossible.

Question: How can one determine when an itinerary/ticket has actually been cancelled. What evidence would be needed to initiate a charge back.

Answer (score 3):

If you bought all the flights as a unit, then the cancellation of any part should count as cancellation of the whole.

You entered into a contract with Air France to get you from one place to another at a particular time. If they can't do this then the contract is cancelled and you get your refund. In normal times they might have been able to give you a viable alternative (replacing one leg with a similar one), but that's not going to happen. In these times you are subject to all the usual delays and caveats that seem to apply to getting refunds, but the principle you should get one.

If you had booked the flights separately then each flight would be subject to separate refund circumstances.